# How to get the Text from Text Box which is clicked, by using VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm working on a Presentation where I have a tabular form of information, where every first column cells have text which function, and I want to get that text from the cell so that I can do something based on the Text.

Here is the function which can help me get the name of the object which is clicked.

```
Sub getText(oShape)
MsgBox oShape.Name
End Sub
```

Here is the [image: Screen Shot]

You'll see Text Box with text **One Two Three**, every word has VBA function given to it. Now what I want is when someone clicks any word, it tells which word is clicked.

Comment: Try looking at `Application.Caller`.

Comment: I can't find `Application.Caller` in PowerPoint VBA

Comment: My mistake, it's in Excel only.

Comment: My mistake... didn't see the powerpoint tag